# Are reactor netty threads and outgoing HTTP connections mapped one to one in spring webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have an application which needs to communicate with two other microservices. Would like to understand how the reactor threads and HTTP connections work together.

When a HTTP request provides response, I guess HTTP connection will be closed only after the idle time.

During this period, do the same http-reactor-epoll threads involved in handling previous request availalble for connections with other service in different host?